# Why does this generator return PI and not 0?

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator

At `generator.prototype.__proto__.math`, the function's argument sets `e = 0`. However, when the `gen.math(1)` is called, the value for `e` seems to be set to 1 instead of 0. Is the initial `e = 0` overwritten by `gen.math(1)` or is there something more?

```
function * generator() {
  yield 1;
}

generator.prototype.__proto__.math = function(e = 0) {
  return e * Math.PI;
}

generator.prototype.__proto__; 

const gen = generator();
gen.math(1); // 3.141592653589793
```

Comment: Have you ever heard of our lord and savior **default arguments**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this behavior has anything to do with generators at all. Your code is essentially equivalent to

```
const math = function(e = 0) {
  return e * Math.PI;
};

math(1);
```

The syntax you use for `e = 0` is a syntax for [Default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters). It doesn't override the supplied parameters. All it does is provide values if parameters have not been supplied. So you can do

```
math()
```

and get `0`.

If you want to ignore argument value you can easily do it in our function body. If your case is more complicated, you might need to use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to set values for parameters.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question first, `function(e = 0)` is defining a function with a *default argument* of e=0. This means that if `e` is not provided, it will default to a value of `0`. For example, when you call just `math()`.

You're calling `math(1)`, which will pass a value for `e` - thus the default will not apply. `e` will simply be the passed in value, which is `1`.

I also want to caution you about modifying `__proto__` - the line you've set up:

```
generator.prototype.__proto__.math = function(e = 0);
```

Is actually defining `math` on the `prototype` of all `Generator`s. You likely didn't intend for this to happen, I assume.

See [__proto__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)'s documentation for more information, and take heed of all of the big red boxes at the top please. :)

Comment: Thank you for the in depth answer! I'm not sure how I forgot about this.